# How to store an object inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I have two arrays and I want to store them in one array and create them as an object.

```
const name = ["Amy", "Robert", "Sofie"];
const age = ["21", "28", "25"];
```

The output I want is:

```
const person =[{name: 'Amy', age: '21'}, {name: 'Robert', age: '28'}, {name: 'Sofie', age: '25'}];
```

Is there a way that I can loop it to make it like this because my array is very long would be bothersome to manually type it. Thanks.

Comment: the length of both the arrays will be same ?

Comment: See https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3z7g6meq9

Comment: if names and ages are even, you can just `name.map(function(e) {return {name: e, age: age[name.indexOf(e)]}}) `

Comment: @marmeladze that only works if there aren't two people with the same name

Comment: Try with this method : https://softans.com/question/how-to-store-an-object-inside-an-array/#comment-496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Array.map like:

```js
const names = ["Amy", "Robert", "Sofie"];
const ages = ["21", "28", "25"];

const persons = names.map((name, i) => ({name, age: ages[i]}));

console.log(persons)
```

Take in consideration that the arrays length have to be equal.
And use *plural* when naming Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the lengths of the two arrays are the same, you can use `map` function to achieve this.

```js
const name = ["Amy", "Robert", "Sofie"];
const age = ["21", "28", "25"];

const person = name.map((nameValue, index) => {
  const ageValue = age[index];
  return { name: nameValue, age: ageValue };
});

console.log(person);
```